# How do you pass value through multiple activities in Android using intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

The project that I'm working on right now currently has 3 screens.
Registration page, Login page and Homepage.
After you register, you are taken back to the login page then from the login page to the homepage.
I can use intents to pass the username from the login page to the home page but I don't know how to pass the String value (user type) from the registration page to the homepage.
It seems like the intent only works when you push the button, that's why I can pass the value from login page to homepage when I press the button that takes me to the homepage.

Comment: you can use this library for easy data sharing: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head I recall two ways:

- On button Click, when starting new activity:

public void nextFormPage(View v) {

```
Intent form_conclusion = new Intent(this, YOURCLASS.class); //define which class to go next

form_conclusion.putExtra("TAG", value);//passes the values to the next activity

startActivity(form_conclusion);                           //start the new activity

finish();

}
```

- Use sharedpreferences to store the value, and read it when needed

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

> - Write
>
>   ```
>   SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
>   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
>   editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore);
>   editor.commit();
>   ```
> - Read
>
>   ```
>   SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
>   int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.saved_high_score_default_key);
>   int highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), defaultValue);
>   ```